# How to return a result in a elegant way in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

The Code A and Code B can work well, but I think that it's not good way in Kotlin, is there a elegant way to do it? Thanks!

**Code A**

```
  private fun getIndexByIntent(data: Intent): Int{
        var index=-1
        var id=getIDByIntent(data)

        for (aIndex in mListBackupItem.indices){
            if (mListBackupItem[aIndex]._id==id){
                index=aIndex
            }
        }    
        return index
    }
```

**Code B**

```
private fun getIndexByIntent(data: Intent): Int{
        var index=-1
        var id=getIDByIntent(data)

        for (aIndex in mListBackupItem.indices){
            if (mListBackupItem[aIndex]._id==id){
                return aIndex
            }
        }
        return index
    }
```

Comment: Code B: return aIndex in for loop

Comment: Code B have two return, and Code A have only one return

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This exact logic is already implemented in the standard library in the form of the [`indexOfFirst`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/index-of-first.html) function, use that:

```
fun getIndexByIntent(data: Intent) : Int {
    val id = getIDByIntent(data)
    return mListBackupItem.indexOfFirst { it._id == id }
}
```